# ObjectiveZlib Not decompressing

Tags: objective-c, ios, gzip

I keep getting inflate error -3 with this code. I have tried different versions of libz. I tried `libz.dylib` and I have tried `libz.1.2.5.dylib` Any suggestions?

```
NSData *originalData = [@"Look out! It's..." dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//use Godzippa to compressed
NSData *compressedData = [originalData dataByGZipCompressingWithError:nil];
//use ObjectiveZlib to decompressed
NSData *decompressedData = [NSData dataByDecompressingData:compressedData];
```

*EDIT*

I got this working in a new project. Now I need to decompress the gz file I receive from the php web server. I get the error from above `dataByDecompressingData:] [Line 94] inflate error: -3`

```
NSData *originalData = [@"Look out! It's..." dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// use ObjectiveZlib to compress
NSData *compressedData2 = [NSData dataByCompressingData:originalData];
//use ObjectiveZlib to decompressed
NSData *decompressedData2 = [NSData dataByDecompressingData:compressedData];
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[decompressedData2 bytes]]);
```

Comment: Did you get an error in the second line? (You're ignoring the error param by using nil there.)

Comment: And if not, does it decompress if you use the symmetric Godzippa decompression method?

Comment: I tried first with Godzippa to decompress it but I got `Error Domain=com.godzippa.zlib.error Code=-2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.godzippa.zlib.error error -2`. According to https://github.com/mattt/Godzippa/issues/1 it is an issue with Godzippa

Comment: Godzippa doesn't give an error when compressing. The above is the error when trying to use godzippa to decompress it's own compressed string. I tried using objectivezlib to decompress the godzippa compressed string but it fails with inflate error -3

Comment: Is the problem with the file that objectivezlib doesn't decompress gzip files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObjectiveZlib compresses to and decompresses from the [zlib](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950) format, not the [gzip](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) format.  If you try to feed a gzip stream to the ObjectiveZlib decompressor, it will properly reject it.

You can modify the ObjectiveZlib source code and write your own ObjectiveGzip.  Change:

```
deflateInit(&stream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION)
```

to:

```
deflateInit2(&stream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, 15+16, 8,
             Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY)
```

and

```
inflateInit(&stream)
```

to:

```
inflateInit2(&stream, 15+16)
```

The `15+16` in both cases requests that zlib use the gzip format instead of the zlib format.  In the `inflateInit2` case if you use `15+32` instead, it will auto-detect whether it is the zlib or gzip format and decode accordingly.

Comment: That's pretty neat. I knew zlib supported both but I'm not well versed in it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up using [GZIP](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP) and it works for gunzip the the gzip file that I download from the webserver.